# Determine constants s.t. a given multistep method has a particular truncation error

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems

Consider the following multistep method 
$$y_n-y_{n-3} + \alpha y_{n-1}-\alpha y_{n-2}=h(\beta f_{n-1}+\beta f_{n-2})$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are undetermined constants.

How would one go about choosing constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ s.t. the truncation error of the method is $O(h^4)$? Moreover, how would you do this in general?

---

I know that given a general linear $m$-step method, 
$$\sum_{n=0}^ma_ny_{k+n}=h\sum_{n=0}^mb_nf(t_{k+n},y_{k+n}),$$
the local truncation error is of order $p\geq 1$ iff
$$\sum_{n=0}^ma_n=0\quad\text{and}\quad \sum_{n=0}^m n^{k}a_n=k\sum_{n=0}^mn^{k-1}b_n$$
for $k=1,\ldots,p$.

However, I'm not sure how to recover the constants from the step where
$$\sum_{n=0}^m n^{k}a_n\ne k\sum_{n=0}^mn^{k-1}b_n.$$

Comment: What you need to do is identify $a_n$'s and $b_n$'s, and write down the condition you wrote for $k=1,2,3,4$. This will give 4 equations, plus another 1 from the condition $\sum_{n=0}^m a_n = 0$. I'm not entirely sure if the condition you wrote down is true since I got confused by the indices, you should double check them.

Comment: Which part of the condition do you think is wrong? I just checked my text and it looks correct.

Comment: I'm used to remembering the sum of $a_n$ equals to 1, but that's also because my professor define the general form of linear multistep method differently from yours. If you already checked it with your text, great!

Comment: So have you figure out how to do this yet?

Comment: @CheeHan, I have not. I set up a system of equations for the conditions imposed by $k=1,2,3,4$. I assumed that $\alpha=1$ and then solved for $\beta$, but the solution for $\beta$ wasn't consistent with the system.

Comment: So I did the computation and show that the given method has truncation error of $\mathcal{O}(h^3)$ only, with $\alpha = 21$ and $\beta = 12$.